# Xml stream read by browser, but fail when loaded with Php

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

I am having some issues with a XML online content. Even before reading it with SimpleXML or any XML parser, I can't access it using a simple file_get_contents() function.
The problem is when I enter the url in my browser, the XML stream loads in 1~2 seconds. How can this be possible?

This is what I try:

```
$url = "http://promotions.marmara.com/Product.asmx/GetOverview?productCode=MARRMAD&brochureName=WEBMARMARA&departureCityCode=&month=&year=&duration=7";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($xml);
```

This is what I get:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://promotions.marmara.com/Product.asmx/GetOverview?productCode=MARRMAD&brochureName=WEBMARMARA&departureCityCode=&month=&year=&duration=7) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in myfile.php on line 4
```

How may it fail to open stream whereas my browser read it so easily? Did i miss something?

Comment: Is your code on the same machine as the browser or is it a server? If it's a server is it on the same network?

Comment: Also in the browser that URI gives a timeout. Looks like you need to login or something similar that is state-based if this is not just some technical quirk. Contact the service-provide of that URI for your support options instead.